# can this left join be safely removed?

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa, spring-data, jpql

I have the following JPA query method in a Spring Data repository

```
public interface UserRoleRepository extends CrudRepository<UserRole, UUID> {

    @Query("""
        from UserRole ur
        join ur.role
        join ur.user
        left join ur.businessUnit
        where ur.user.id = :userId""")
    List<UserRole> getUserRoles(UUID userId);
}
```

Given that no predicates are applied to `ur.businessUnit`, can this query be simplified to

```
from UserRole ur
join ur.role
join ur.user
where ur.user.id = :userId
```

Each user role either has 0 or 1 associated business units. In JPA terms, this is defined in the `UserRole` class as:

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "business_unit_id")
private BusinessUnit businessUnit;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A left join is cardinality preserving, so as long as you don't refer to the join alias (which doesn't even exist in your case), it is safe to remove the join.